# Why is the ICommand not triggered in my MAUI app?

Tags: mvvm, maui, icommand

At the XAML I got a button using a command:

```xml
<Button Text="Month" Command="{Binding SetMonthCommand}"/>
```

At the ViewModel class I implement the Command:

```cs
public ICommand SetMonthCommand()
{
    IsMontHActive = true;
    IsListActive = !IsMontHActive;
    return null;
}
```

**But this method is never called (by clicking the button).
What is missing?**

My XAML implements the ViewModels by namespace.

```xml
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
```

My ViewModel is bound to the XAML in *.cs* file:

```cs
this.BindingContext = _calendarPageViewModel;
```

I tried using the *ICommand* as public property, but when I click the button, the setter is not reached.

```cs
private ICommand _setMonatCommand; 
public ICommand SetMonatCommand 
{ 
    get { return _setMonatCommand; } 
    set { 
        _setMonatCommand = value; 
        IsMonatActive = true; 
        IsListeActive = !IsMonatActive; 
    }
}
```

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties**

Comment: make `SetMonthCommand` a **public property**

Comment: please [edit] your question, do not stuff code into comments.  There are numerous examples of how to bind to a command in a VM

Comment: @Jason Yes, I studied the the examples and tutorials, but I can't get it working.

Comment: have you set the `BindingContext`?  Just declaring the `xmlns` doesn't really do anything by itself

Comment: @Jason Yes I did: this.BindingContext = _calendarPageViewModel;

Comment: are you assigning a value to the Command property?  The code you posted is not the correct way to do it.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/commanding?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a public property

```
public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }
```

then in your constructor set it

```
MyCommand = new ICommand( () => {
  IsMontHActive = true;
  IsListActive = !IsMontHActive;
});
```